# Display (repeater field) images only of the custom post opened

Tags: php, html, css

I´m displaying the images (that are in a repeater field of ACF) with this code:

```
<?php $query = new WP_Query( 'post_type=artworks_post&posts_per_page=-1&order=DESC' ); ?>
<?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

<?php $slides = get_field('project_slider');// Grabs the array

    // Check if there is any data in the array before looping
    if($slides) {
        echo '<div id="slideshow">';
        echo '<ul id="slides">';
        foreach($slides as $s) {
            echo '<li>';
            echo '<img src="'.$s['project_image'].'" alt="" height="480" />';
            echo '<span>'.$s['project_title'].'</span>';
            echo '<span class="project_description">'.$s['project_description'].'</span>';
            echo '</li>';
        }
            echo '</ul>';
    }               

?>

<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

The problem is that it shows the images of the repeater field of all custom post (artworks_post), not the one i´m looking in the page. How can I limit it to show only the images of the opened post?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add the parameter page_id

```
<?php $query = new WP_Query( 'post_type=artworks_post&posts_per_page=-1&order=DESC&page_id=' . the_ID() ); ?>
```

Comment: I pasted this and no different thing happened, thank you anyway